# SwiftUI Preview Does Not Work with Core Data when Entity Injected in View

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I've been frustrated for months trying to get previews to work in Xcode when Core Data
is used. I can definitely make the preview work for the views that don't include an
injected item. But not any subsequent views that depend on the source Entity.

Let's say I have a master/detail-like SwiftUI project with ContentView containing
my list and ThingDetailView showing the detail for the entity Thing.

I created a wrapper for the preview of ContentView:

```
struct PreviewCoreDataWrapper<Content: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    let content: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let managedObjectContext = viewContext
    
        let sampleThing = Thing(context: managedObjectContext)
        sampleThing.name = "Sample Name"
        sampleThing.comment = "Sample Comment"
        sampleThing.id = UUID()
        //more attributes

        return self.content(managedObjectContext)
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Then the preview in ContentView, this WORKS.

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    
        PreviewCoreDataWrapper { managedObjectContext in
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

But then in the detail view, no matter what I have tried, I cannot get the
preview to work. I've tried dozens of ways to satisfy the injected Thing call.

```
struct ThingDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PreviewCoreDataWrapper { managedObjectContext in
            ThingDetailView(thing: sampleThing).environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Xcode Version 12.0 (12A7208), iOS 14

The ThingDetailView is pretty standard stuff:

```
struct ThingDetailView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var managedObjectContext

    var thing: Thing

    @State private var localName: String = ""
    @State private var localComment: String = ""
    //bunch more properties

    var body: some View {
    
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.localName = self.thing.wrappedName
            self.localComment = self.thing.wrappedComment
            //buch more properties
        }//dispatch
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if !showEditView {
            localNewUIImage = UIImage(data: thing.tImage)
            }
        }
    
        //you need this to allow the TextEditor background to be changed
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear

        return ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            
                //this is for an image
                if !showEditView {
                ThingHeaderView(thing: thing)
                } else {
                    NewPhotoView(myImage: $localMyImage, newUIImage: $localNewUIImage, disableSaveButton: $localDisableSaveButton)
                }
            
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Group {//group 1
                        //MARK: name
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            if !showEditView {
                                Text("\(thing.wrappedName)")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                                    .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("CardBlue"))
                            } else {
                                TextField("tf name", text: self.$localName)
                                    .modifier(TextFieldSetup())
                            }
                        }//name v
                    
                        //MARK: comment
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            if !showEditView {
                                Text("\(thing.wrappedComment)")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                                    .font(.headline)
                            } else {
                                TextEditor(text: self.$localComment)
                                    .modifier(TextEditorSetup())
                            }
                        }//comment v
                        //bunch more TextFields and TextEditors
                    }//group 1
                }//inner v
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .frame(maxWidth: 640, alignment: .center)
            }//outer v
        
            //seems like a title is needed to remofe large space at top - then hide
            .navigationBarTitle(thing.wrappedName, displayMode: .inline)
            //.navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(showEditView)
            .navigationBarItems(
            
                leading:
                    Button(action: {
                        if showEditView {
                            self.showEditView = false
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text(showEditView ? "Cancel" : "")
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                    },
                trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        if !showEditView {
                            print("showEditView is \(showEditView)")
                            self.showEditView = true
                        } else {
                            self.saveEditedRecord()
                            self.showEditView = false
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: self.showEditView ? "square.and.arrow.down.fill" : "square.and.pencil")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    }//images
                    .disabled(self.localDisableSaveButton)
            )//nav bar item
        }//scroll
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }//body

    func saveEditedRecord() {
        print("...and you are in the save function...")
        let context = self.managedObjectContext
        thing.id = UUID()
        //all the rest and 
        //standard Core Data save
    }//save record
}//struct thing detail view
```

And the ThingHeaderView:

```
struct ThingHeaderView: View {

    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass
    @State private var isAnimatingImage: Bool = false

    var thing: Thing

    var body: some View {
    
        let sc = sizeClass == .compact
    
        return ZStack {
        
            if UIImage(data: thing.tImage) != nil {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: thing.tImage)!)
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(color: (Color.black.opacity(0.5)), radius: 8, x: 10, y: 10)
                    .padding(sc ? 6 : 10)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "camera.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                isAnimatingImage = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show ThingDetailView code? And what is `sampleThing` in your last snapshot?

Comment: I added above. sampleThing is nothing - the only purpose is to identify that Xcode wants to be passed a Thing.

Answer (score 4):

The way I've always handled Core Data in previews is not by using a "PreviewCoreDataWrapper", but to instead define my viewContext and add the properties in the previews before I return my view to preview.

```swift
struct ThingDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext

    static var previews: some View {
        let sampleThing = Thing(context: viewContext)
        sampleThing.name = "Sample Name"
        sampleThing.comment = "Sample Comment"
        sampleThing.id = UUID()
        //more attributes

        return ThingDetailView(thing: sampleThing).environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
    }
}
```

This usually works for me. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I have actually tried that but I receive the error: "Instance member 'viewContext' cannot be used on type 'ThingDetailView_Previews'".  On the line: let sampleThing = Thing(context: viewContext)

Comment: Sorry I forgot, the view context needs to be static since previews is static. @user2698617

Comment: That did get rid of the error mentioned above - but the preview still does not run. I guess I need to abandon the preview tool and get on with it.